# Find the radius of convergence of Maclaurin series of $(1 + z)^α$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Question]

I was able to figure out the expansion of Maclaurin series, and the radius of convergence. But my answer seems wrong. My radius of convergence was $0$.

Comment: Please show us how you reached this conclusion.

Comment: Hint: as there is a singularity at $z=-1$ for some values of $\alpha$, you can expect the radius to be bounded by $1$ in some cases. But for positive integer $\alpha$, the development is a mere polynomial, giving an infinite radius. So the answer is certainly more complex than $0$.

Comment: so I used the branch of log, if a^b = exp(b log a). so exp(a log(1+z)) in this case for the Maclaurin series.

Comment: Agree with @YvesDaoust ... We cannot tell you what you did wrong, unless you tell us what you did.